# min-height style not working on button unless other style is present

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

In the following HTML, the `min-height` style property does nothing in (my versions of) Chrome and Safari on Mac, but does work in Firefox:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button style='min-height:50px;'>
                hello
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also noticed that the `min-height` property takes effect in Chrome and Safari if some *other* unrelated property is added to the button, such as `background-color:#abc;`.

Is this some known webkit bug, possibly part of a larger class of bugs I should be aware of? Or not a bug at all?

Thanks!

Comment: No, that works as is in the browsers you mentioned, which means you likely have set the buttons elsewhere.

Comment: @LGSon I don't understand your comment about "setting the buttons elsewhere". Even when I press "run code snippet" in the demo it doesn't work, so it's not like I've confused my files or something. Same issue in Safari, but like I said, not in Firefox. Chrome version: 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: I'd just runned it with my Chrome (Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)), no issue, max height applied

Comment: OK well I just ran the code snippet in mine again, and the issue persists... I guess there's some other variable at work. Have you tried Safari? (Btw it's min-height, not max-height, but anyway.)

Answer (score -1):

It's working on my side. Please try with this

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button style='min-height:50px;display:inline-block'>
        hello
    </button>
</body>
```

Comment: I have updated code if you check it properly, go through the code again that you can find what i have changed

Comment: No one should need to go through a code to find what is changed. Read my first comment again, and here if you need more clarifications on [answer]